# Grails save one to many Domain Model

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

Hi I'm new in Grails have some issue with the to save Data to DomainModel.

I have 2 Domains Poll and Answeroption
Which has a one to Many relationship.

I dont see why my object is null...
Error Message: 
Cannot invoke method save() on null object

PollDomain:
package exercise

```
class Poll {
    static hasMany = [answerOptions: AnswerOption]

    String questionid
    String question
    boolean manyAnswer = false;

    static constraints = {
    }

}
```

AnswerOption Domain:

```
package exercise

class AnswerOption{

    Integer answerid
    String option
    Integer voted = 0;

    static belongsTo = [poll: Poll]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

PollController:

```
package exercise

class PollController {
    PollService p
    Poll poll
    AnswerOption answerOption

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", vote: "GET", delete: "DELETE"]

    def create() {
        respond( new Poll(params))
        [poll: flash.redirectParams]
        [answerOption: flash.redirectParams]
    }

    def save() {
        def response = p.save(params)
        if (!response.isSuccess) {
            flash.redirectParams = response.model
            redirect(controller: "member", action: "create")
        }else{
            redirect(controller: "member", action: "vote")
        }
    }

    def vote() {

    }
}
```

PollService:

```
package exercise
import grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional
import grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsParameterMap

@Transactional
class PollService {
    Poll poll
    AnswerOption answerOption

    def save(GrailsParameterMap params) {

        String qid = AppUtil.generateRandomString()
        println(qid)
        def poll = new Poll(questionid: qid, question: params.question, manyAnswer: params.manyAnswer)

        if (poll == null) {
            println("poll is Null")
        }else{
            println("Not Null")
        }

        def response = AppUtil.saveResponse(false, poll)
        if (poll.validate()) {
            poll.save(flush: true)
            if (!p.hasErrors()){
                response.isSuccess = true
            }
        }
        params.list("option").eachWithIndex { item, index ->
            answerOption=  new AnswerOption(answerid: index, option: item, poll:poll).save(flush: true)
        }

        return response
    }

}
```

Comment: Would be great if you could provide a stacktrace and this looks like a simple problem you can easily solve your self by using a debugger. 
Stepping through your code and you will see immediately the cause of your bug.

Comment: On which line number problem is coming Please share .@Anas

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that your `NullPointerException` happens in `PollController.save` where you try to call the service's save method:

```
def response = p.save(params)
```

This seems strange to me, because you declared the dependency to the PollService as a simple class member:

```
PollService p
```

afaik, by default Grails only sets dependencies by name, not by type. so renaming this particular field to "pollService" should improve your situation:

```
class PollController {
    PollService pollService
    ...
    def save() {
        def response = pollService.save(params)
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, you always declare (but not use) fields for you 2 domain classes in the controller and the service, you won't need that and you even wouldn't want that. But, that's not part the question ;-)